# Passport overwrite users

Tags: express, pug, passport.js

the problem is that when I login with 2 users, the second overwrite the first user.

I have this code to passport localStrategy

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
  var passEncriptada = encriptar(username, password);
  process.nextTick(function () {
     UserDetails.findOne({'name':username},
       function(err, user) {
         if (err) { return done(err); }
         if (!user) { return done(null, false); }
         if (user.password != passEncriptada) { return done(null, false); }
         return done(null, user);
      });
 });
```

}
));

And, when I login with a user, I go to the / view and use the req.user

```
app.get('/', function(req,res){
var user = req.user;
    res.render('index', {
        title: 'Ejemplo de Passport JS',
        user: user
    });   
});
```

What can I do to separate the two users login?

You can see the full code [here](https://ide.c9.io/alu0100786330/usa), in app.js

Comment: Are you testing within the same browser?

Comment: Yes, I use Google Chrome

Answer (score 3):

Passport (by default) tracks logged in users by means of a session key. This key is stored in the browser by means of a cookie.

If you're using the same browser to log in as a second user while you are already logged in, the cookie of the first user will be *overwritten* with the cookie of the second user. You can only be logged in as one user, specifically the user that you logged in as last.

You should be able to test your backend by logging in as a second user from a different browser (because browsers don't share their cookies).